# my model is not showing in gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

my model is not showing under insert tab, here i am showing step by step procedure of what i have done

Step 1 I want test1 model to be shown up in gazebo
[C:\fakepath\Screenshot from 2018-06-11 17:54:57.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/1528719919892818.png)

Step 2 I have sdf file and config file, also .dae file in meshes folder [C:\fakepath\Screenshot from 2018-06-11 17:58:15.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/1528720122153063.png)

Step 3 screen shot of config and sdf file [C:\fakepath\Screenshot from 2018-06-11 17:59:49.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/15287202558051067.png)
[C:\fakepath\Screenshot from 2018-06-11 18:01:31.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/15287203058735505.png)

Step 4 Finally in step 4 when i open gazebo then under insert tab this is what i get
[C:\fakepath\Screenshot from 2018-06-11 18:02:29.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/1528720412397376.png)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/19654/my-model-is-not-showing-in-gazebo/) by [rohit18mittal](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5563/rohit18mittal/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Here are some problems I spotted:

- The config file cannot have an arbitrary name, it **must** be called `model.config`, you're calling it `camera.config`
- The root element of the `.sdf` file **must** be `<model>`, you currently have `<world>`

When you launch gazebo, run it in verbose mode so you can see error messages that should give you more clues:

```
gazebo --verbose
```

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rohit18mittal](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5563/rohit18mittal/) on 2018-06-12**:
thanks for your reply, i will correct it

**Comment by [rohit18mittal](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5563/rohit18mittal/) on 2018-06-12**:
thanks a ton chapulina, my model is now showing in gazebo
Thank you very much